# NodeJS: Download file from url and upload to S3 Strorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fs

I'm trying to accomplish the following task: I need to download image from url, then upload it to S3 storage and return the location of the uploaded file. I'm using async/await functions to do the task, but it returns Promise { pending } and after few seconds returns the location, i want to return location after promise is resolved. Here is my code:

```
    // Space config
    const spaceEndPoint = new AWS.Endpoint("fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com");
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      endpoint: spaceEndPoint,
      accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxx",
      secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    });

    // Download image from url
    const downloadImage = async (url) => {
      try {
        const file = axios
          .get(url, {
            responseType: "stream",
          })
          .then((res) => res.data)
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        return file;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    
    // Upload to space
    const upload = async (fileUrl) => {

      // Get file name from url
      const fileName = path.basename(fileUrl);

      // Path to save tmp file
      const localFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../downloads", fileName);

      // Download file
      const file = await downloadImage(fileUrl);

      // Write file to disk
      await file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath));

      // Upload params
      const params = {
        Bucket: "sunday",
        Body: fs.createReadStream(localFilePath),
        Key: path.basename(fileName),
        ContentType: "application/octet-stream",
        ACL: "public-read",
      };
    
      const { Location } = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    
      return Location;
    };
    
    console.log(
      upload(
        "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/e9/62/7c/e9627ce6fe731ba49597d3a83e21e398.jpg"
      ).then((data) => data)
    );

// Result:
Promise { <pending> }
https://sunday.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/e9627ce6fe731ba49597d3a83e21e398.jpg
```

So i want to return location when promise is resolved.
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Your function `upload` is async and thus always returns a promise that should be `await`ed too. `await` your `upload` call. If you're in environment that doesn't support top level `await`, use `.then` to log results instead or put outer logging code in helper function.